# Make simultaneosly JSoup requests

Tags: java, multithreading, jsoup, threadpool

I have to send multiple http request to my server and want to do it in a simultaneosly (multithreading) way.
Below is the code that I developed until now. This is the `Main` class in with I retrieve the number of cores of my CPU and create as many threads as cores.

```
public class Main {
private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Request> reqList = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Request>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {        

    Integer countOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();  

    Worker worker1 = new Worker(new Request("sxafsfle9il.comasfasf","bfasf91"));
    Worker worker2 = new Worker(new Request("sxafsfle9il.comasfasf","bfasf91")); 

    MultiThreading.start(countOfThreads, worker1);
    MultiThreading.start(countOfThreads, worker2);

}
}
```

The `Worker` class implements the `Runnable` interface and run each task in a separate thread:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
  private Request reqToChecking;

  public Worker(Request req) {
      this.reqToChecking = req;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {        

       try {

           reqToChecking.callWebServer();

       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

   }

}
```

The Request class that use JSoup to make http request and do some stuff:

```
public class Request {
   private String param1;
   private String param2;

   public Request(String p1, String p2) throws IOException {        
     param1 = p1;
     param2 = p2;
   }

   public void callWebserver() throws IOException {
     // send some requests to server

   }
 }
```

Finally, the Multithreading class that starts thread:

```
public class MultiThreading {
    public static  void start(Integer numberOfThread, Runnable task) {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThread);
        //threadPool.submit(task);
        threadPool.execute(task);
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

This multithreading version is faster only for few second than the version without multithread.
In your opinion, is it correct the code above? If not, could you give some advice to improve this code? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? Did you check in the debugger how many threads are running? Please don't ask for code review, especially before you have tested thoroughly yourself.

Comment: Yes, I run it. And this multithreading version is faster only for few second than the version without multithread.

Comment: Did you check that it was actually multithreading? That is, that more than one thread is handling the tasks?

Comment: No, but I think is doing that and Il'l check soon. Anyway, in your opinion, is the code correct?

Comment: I update the code and It seems that now the whole work is splitted among threads.

Comment: Two threads, I imagine. Not the number of threads that you calculated. Anyway, do you have any improvement with two threads?

Comment: No, in fact as I wrote to @efekctive's answer if I made few request is not convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads have a cost. So the time that you save has to account for this cost and in addition execute in less time than in sequential code.

In some circumstances, they may not be worthwhile.

In your case seconds can be a huge save in relative terms. Take into account that some operations can be measured in microseconds or less.

This line:

```
 threadPool.shutdown();
```

is optimistic. If one of the threads is stuck, then it will never shutdown.

**EDIT**

```
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThread);
```

needs to be used only once. Outside the method.

I usually check the active count using a time to live before calling shutdown. If it is exceeded then proper action can be taken.

In pseudo code:

```
loop a number of times
if threadPoolExceutor.getActiveCount() != 0
sleep certain amount
else
break out of loop

if loop was completed
 check  still running threads.
else
 success
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your opinion my code is correct? I've update few minutes ago. I noticed that with few task is better work without multithread, vice versa it will more suitable use multithread. And how I can better handle `threadPool.shutdown();`?

Comment: If this helps you would you mind to accept the answer?

Comment: I can't understand last sentence... have I to declarate something like a global counter? If you have some code, please, add in the answer. Then I'll accept it :)